# Error: 'npm install -g @ionic/cli' gives me '4 high severity vulnerabilities' & 'ERR! errno -4058'

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, npm-install, capacitor

I get this message **'4 high severity vulnerabilities'** after running the command **'npm install -g @ionic/cli'** on Windows 10.  When I do the subsequent **'ionic start'** command I get warning messages and the execution hangs.

**Details:**

1. Computer OS: **Windows 10**
2. Installed everything from: **node-v16.13.0-x64.msi** and this gave me:
   **node Version 16.13.0**, and
   **npm Version  8.1.0**
3. **'npm install -g @ionic/cli'** gave this message:
   ...
   4 high severity vulnerabilities
   ...
4. (a) **npm audit** gave:
   ...
   npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
   npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
   ...
   (b) **npm i --package-lock-only** gave:
   ...
   npm ERR! errno -4058
   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\Projects\Ionic\package.json'
   ...
5. When I tried the **'npm audit fix --force'** it was unsuccessful for I got more errors, Example:
   npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
   npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
   npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
   npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
   npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
   ...
6. Examples of error messages that occur after executing **'ionic start'**:
   ... 
    npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest
   npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
   npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.4',
   npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
   npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
   npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
   npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
   npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
   npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.0', npm: '8.1.0' }
   npm WARN EBADENGINE }
   ...
   Eventually ends up hanging also.

**Any help would be appreciated to fix this problem I am facing.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update to 6.18.1

There was a vulnerability in one dependency of one of the @ionic/cli dependencies and has been updated to a version that doesn't present the vulnerability.